# png terminal in gnuplot

Tags: 13.10, png

I have :

- Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit
- wxMaxima 13.04.2 ( Maximy:5.31.3 )
- Lisp:SBCL 1.1.1.0.debian
- gnuplot version 4.6 patchlevel 4    last modified 2013-10-06

When I check terminals in gnuplot using :

```
set terminal
```

then I do not see png terminal.

What should I do to change it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[png terminal is related](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node409.html) with [gd library](http://libgd.bitbucket.org/) so I have to :

1. install gd library
2. reinstall gnuplot from source file

Answer (score 0):

To set png as the output file format of your graph you need to set the following in your `*.gnu` file:

```
set terminal png
set output filename.png
```

Comment: the png terminal is not on the list of available terminals so I can not use it. The problem is why ?

Comment: How do you know it is not available, how did you check that?

Comment: run gnuplot , then type set terminal. Then you will have a list of all available terminals. png is not on that list. I think that is a problem with libpg and libz libraries

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me to get the PNG terminal was typing,

```
sudo apt-get install libgd2-noxpm-dev
```

then re-compiling and re-installing gnuplot.

Comment: Why do we need to re-compile ?